# how do I avoid php from going up to a certain directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, dedicated-server

Not much ago I upgraded to a dedicated server, and I order to make it more cost efficient for me, I decided rent some space on the server to people I know (friends, family). Some of the people I know have some other guy that is in charge of the website development, and I want to protect myself from an unauthorized access to my, or any of the other guys I rented to.

One of the cases which concerns me the most is PHP getting access to other users or me by accessing `../` from their root.

For instance, they could do something like this: **`foreach(glob('../*/*.*') as $some_file){unlink($some_file);}`** which would delete all the files from a sibling user.

How do I avoid people from doing this sort of things?

Comment: Whenever you have user input which is passed into a file access function, always validate with `strpos()` the presence of `../` and also check for the presence of NULL bytes.

Comment: The name for this malicious behavior, incidentally, is a [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack)

Comment: i would use something designed for managing a machine in this circumstance like cPanel & WHM (seems most shared hosts use it); getting it wrong could be a serious problem

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586219/is-ascii-the-only-byte-sequence-that-indicates-a-directory-traversal-in-ph

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue that can be resolved through system administration.

- Edit your php.ini file, restricting the values in open_basedir
- Make sure your users are assigned to different groups
- chmod your home directories og-wx (e.g. 744, 740, 700, etc...)
- Run multiple instances of apache server, possibly under different users/groups

It really depends on how much effort you want to put into it and how robust the security needs to be.

---

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances

Answer (score 0):

You should consider dctrucker post on permissions and make sure the apache process if you are running php with mod_php or the php processes if you are running it on fast-cgi dont have the permissions to change permissions. I wouldnt advice the base_opendir approach if security is your concern because then one can just use ini_set to override it (so if using that approach you should disable ini_set as well ).